# Setting maximum number of threads for Snakemake cluster profile

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I am using the [Snakemake slurm](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm) profile with a workflow that contains a number of rules that specify `threads: 24`. The cluster I am running on only has a few nodes with 24 cores, but many with 20 cores. How can I specify (preferably in the profile) the maximum number of threads to use for any rule?

Comment: You could modify the submission [script in the profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/slurm/blob/a4abc2123e7c7b66f346e8d34601632700ac11a2/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.profile_name%7D%7D/slurm_utils.py#L114) to take the min of threads and 20, but it wouldn't feed back into the snakemake job.  I think for that you would also have to update the jobscript.

Comment: Thanks @TroyComi, that is exactly what I ended up doing. It works, but Snakemake still thinks it's using 24 threads. The old system of a cluster config would override the Snakefile rules, which was useful for this sort of thing. It seems the profile system is lacking a bit in this respect. The choice of threads could change depending on the input data, cluster config, etc.